# « Les projets de recherche que j'ai intégré/intégrés » : Accord ou pas ?

Tags: accord

> Le document est dévolu à mon Curriculum Vitae synthétique, synthétisant mes formations suivies, mon parcours professionnel, mes enseignements prodigués, les responsabilités collectives auxquelles j'ai participé ainsi que **les projets de recherche que j'ai intégré** en tant que chercheur contractuel ou chercheur associé contractuel.

Est-ce'il faut écrire *les projets de recherche que j'ai intégré**S*** ?

Comment: Un problème de sens que je n'avais pas vu : « participer pas à une responsabilité » n'est pas très logique ; endosser : 1. [Le suj. joue un rôle actif] Prendre sur soi. Synon. assumer, se charger de. Dans toutes ces citations, je ne prétends pas endosser les passages que j'emprunte (SAINTE-BEUVE, Caus. lundi, t. 5, 1851-62, p. 232). Celui qui s'en lave les mains pour esquiver l'alternative **endosse** au contraire la plus lourde des **responsabilités** (JANKÉL., Je-ne-sais-quoi, 1957, p. 226)

Comment: *mes enseignements prodigués* ⇨ *les enseignements que j'ai prodigués*

Comment: @LPH Afin que je sois sûr, tu veux dire qu'il me faut reformuler comme ci-après ? Le document est dévolu à mon Curriculum Vitae synthétique, synthétisant mes formations suivies, mon parcours professionnel, les enseignements que j'ai prodigués, **les responsabilités collectives que j'ai endossés** ainsi que les projets de recherche que j'ai intégrés en tant que chercheur contractuel ou chercheur associé contractuel.

Comment: @LPH : 1/  Dévolu : https://books.google.fr/books?id=SM9wDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA139&lpg=PA139&dq=le+premier+chapitre+est+d%C3%A9volu&source=bl&ots=iSEsVlVU_g&sig=ACfU3U35J_xdz03ph8a5w36wrazf3qha5g&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiZ8sGCk4rhAhWozYUKHcn5D0IQ6AEwBHoECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=le%20premier%20chapitre%20est%20d%C3%A9volu&f=false

Comment: @LPH 2/ Le document concerne un dossier de postulation comportant plusieurs chapitres ; le premier étant le CV synthétique. Le passage de la question est extrait d'avant propos.

Comment: @LPH Je vous remercie de votre intérêt ! Malheureusement je n'ai pas de temps pour en parler.

Comment: @LPH C'est noté:-)! Merci encore.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Projet de recherche" agit ici comme un nom, il me semble donc évident qu'il faille accorder avec ce nom qui est au pluriel, donc effectivement :

> Les projets de recherche que j'ai intégrés

D'ailleurs, si on omet la précision "de recherche", la phrase ne perd pas nécessairement beaucoup de sens et l'accord devient plus évident :

> Les projets que j'ai intégrés

Soit dit en passant, je me demande également si la formulation est totalement correcte. Selon moi on participe, on collabore à un projet, et on intègre l'équipe qui travaille à ce projet. Donc "les projets de recherche que j'ai intégrés" est en fait un abus de language (selon moi tout à fait acceptable et largement compréhensible) pour dire :

> Les projets de recherche auxquels j'ai collaboré/participé

Comment: Il semble ne pas y avoir de doute, je suis du même avis : collaborer à un projet, participer à un projet, travailler à un projet, …(+1 pour la sémantique)