# Emploi du mot « partenarial »

Tags: usage, néologismes, dictionnaires

Extrait tiré d'une fiche d'un poste de Maître des Conférences :

> De plus, le ou la candidat(e) devra participer aux travaux de recherche **partenariale**
>   déjà engagés dans l’équipe et en développer de nouveaux (régionaux, nationaux et
>   européens). Ces travaux devront trouver des débouchés auprès de nos partenaires
>   industriels, socioéconomiques et universitaires, et favoriser par ailleurs le transfert de
>   technologie, notamment dans le cadre des pôles de compétitivité.

Je me demande pourquoi :

A/ L'éditeur de texte de Windows ne reconnait pas le mot *partenarial(e)*.

B/ Le TLFi ne parle pas de ce mot bien que [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/partenarial_partenariale_partenariaux/58353) en ligne en parle. [Wiki](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/partenarial) en parle aussi mais le lemme me semble peu complet.

Aditionnellement, quand faut-il employer *partenarial* et quand *partenariat* ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A/ Il n'existe pas dans le TLFi et dans le dictionnaire de l'Académie ; on le trouve dans le [Larousse en ligne](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/partenarial_partenariale_partenariaux/58353) ; il a donc été omis dans le programme.

Dans le présent cas, je ne sais pas si l'on doit vraiment parler de néologisme ; il doit se trouver que l'adjectif n'ayant pas été utilisé par le passé, il manquait dans les dictionnaires, tout simplement ; cet [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partenarial&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartenarial%3B%2Cc0) tend beaucoup à confirmer cela.

B/ C'est très simple ; les deux mots sont le nom et l'adjectif construits sur la même racine ; le suffixe « **-at** » produit souvent des noms et le suffixe « **-al** » produit des adjectifs.

> électeur/électorat/électoral, partenaire/partenariat/partenarial, patron/patronat/patronal

- des résolutions patronale, une association patronale, …
- le patronat prend de nouvelles mesures, l'électorat décide, des lois électorales, …

Comment: Merci ; alors le mot partenarial existe-t-il officiellement ou non ? est-ce un néologisme ?

Comment: Merci encore ; c'est logique : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=partenarial&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cpartenarial%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Tes commentaires méritent d'être résumés et ensuite rajoutés à la réponse ; le diagramme aussi.

Comment: @Dimitris Dès qu'un des dictionnaires importants comporte un mot, ne fût-ce, qu'un seul des dictionnaire, il n'y a pas à hésiter, il existe et on peut l'utiliser. Si c'est un mot d'argot ou familier, de toute façon il n'y a aucun problème parce que l'on ne se sert pas de ceux-là dans le texte, donc on ne les cherche pas. Le Larousse ne parle pas de néologisme ; pour ma part cela me semble un mot très naturel que je comprends sans jamais l'avoir vu parce qu'il est de la famille de « partenaire » et « partenariat » ; comme en plus lorsqu'on le trouve il modifie un nom, (champ 1)

Comment: @Dimitris et que la terminaison indique un adjectif, je sais qu'il signifie « de la nature du partenariat, qui caractérise l'état, la condition de partenaire ».

Comment: @Dimitris Vous laissez tomber votre recherche sur le texte concernant un CV ?

Comment: Je n'arrive pas à comprendre le dernier commentaire.

Comment: @Dimitris C'est à propos de ceci https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/34271/les-projets-de-recherche-que-jai-int%c3%a9gr%c3%a9-int%c3%a9gr%c3%a9s-accord-ou-pas#comment70266_34271

Answer (score 1):

Complement à l'autre réponse. Voici quelques emplois courants du mot partenarial (source [Cordial](https://www.cordial.fr/dictionnaire/definition/partenarial.php)):

> approche partenariale "Pour compléter et améliorer la formation des
>   enseignants, les notions d'éducation et de prévention doivent être
>   prises en compte dans les formations initiales et continues, ainsi que
>   dans une approche partenariale, notamment avec les éducateurs." (Sénat
>   1994-2005 "Examens de projets de lois et débats")
>
> cadre partenarial "Mettre fin à la cogestion en matière d'insertion
>   sociale et professionnelle des bénéficiaires du RMI en clarifiant les
>   compétences respectives de l'Etat et des collectivités territoriales
>   dans un cadre partenarial." (Sénat 1994-2005 "Examens de projets de
>   lois et débats")
>
> dispositif partenarial "Enfin, a rapporté M. Monteil, l'université
>   doit être placée au coeur d'un dispositif partenarial, non seulement
>   avec l'Etat mais aussi avec les collectivités territoriales et les
>   entreprises." (AFP 1997 "Dépêches de l'AFP, juin 1997")
>
> dynamique partenariale "Pour réussir, une telle dynamique partenariale
>   et transversale au niveau de la région ne doit pas s'opposer à la
>   rigidité de mesures verticales décidées par le pouvoir central
>   parisien pour application uniforme sur l'ensemble du territoire." (Le
>   Monde 1993 "Extrait du Monde de mai 1993")
>
> démarche partenariale "procéder à l'évaluation des instances
>   régionales ou locales de la politique de santé publique au regard des
>   exigences d'une politique décentralisée de lutte contre le cancer et
>   identifier, le cas échéant, les adaptations nécessaires pour garantir
>   une démarche partenariale et coordonnée de l'ensemble des acteurs
>   concernés," (Site Web français 2005 "Page de site médical français")
>
> gestion partenariale "Sans remettre en cause le principe de la gestion
>   partenariale et paritaire (9), l'Etat, désormais, transmet les
>   impulsions de sa politique de santé par la double technique du contrat
>   et du contrôle, sous menace, le cas échéant, de contrainte." (Le Monde
>   Diplomatique 1990-2007 "Article du Monde Diplomatique")
>
> logique partenariale "une logique globale et une logique
>   partenariale." (Véronique Chorain 2001 "Les aides aux entreprises :
>   les actions innovantes des collectivités locales dans un cadre
>   juridique figé")
>
> manière partenariale "C'est alors que pourra s'engager la
>   préparationdu contrat de plan lui-même, qui permettra de déterminer de
>   manière partenariale, parmi les actions prioritaires, celles qui
>   pourront faire l'objet d'un financement, qu'elles soient proposées par
>   la région, par le représentant de l'Etat, ou, le plus souvent je
>   pense, parles deux." (Le Monde 1999 "Extrait du Monde de 1999")
>
> politique partenariale "Il est également nécessaire d'envisager cette
>   politique partenariale dans la durée." (Véronique Chorain 2001 "Les
>   aides aux entreprises : les actions innovantes des collectivités
>   locales dans un cadre juridique figé")
>
> relations partenariales "moyens matériels mis à disposition, relations
>   partenariales avec les entreprises, ou avec les universités françaises
>   et étrangères, qualité de l'environnement économique et culturel sont
>   autant de facteurs qui séduisent ou dissuadent les futurs
>   enseignants." (Le Monde 1992 "Extrait du Monde d'avril 1992")
>
> scénario partenarial "Convaincue au contraire du bien fondé d'un
>   scénario partenarial, qui devrait d'ailleurs concerner l'ensemble des
>   assurés sociaux et non les seuls assurés titulaires des plus bas
>   revenus, votre commission vous propose de supprimer cet article."
>   (Sénat 1994-2005 "Examens de projets de lois et débats")
>
> travail partenarial "L'ARF se prononce donc pour un pilotage plus
>   clair du programme au niveau national qui pourrait être ainsi décliné
>   par région pour faciliter le travail partenarial entre les régions et
>   les services déconcentrés." (Sénat 1994-2005 "Examens de projets de
>   lois et débats")